# How to Set ActiveWindow.Zoom in Excel Through Access VBA?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to create a macro in VBA that will format an Excel sheet through Access VBA.  I came up against some surprises in Access which wouldn't recognize certain Excel VBA commands like `.Select`, `.Interior.Color`, and `.ActiveWindow.Zoom`.  I got around the first two problems but can somebody help me with setting the Active Zoom to 90%?

```
Sub ExcelMacro()

Dim xlApp As Object
Dim xlWB As Object

filepath = "\\dom1...xlsm"

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

xlApp.Workbooks.Open filepath

xlApp.Visible = True

xlApp.Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Set xlWB = xlApp.ActiveWorkbook

xlWB.Sheets(1).ActiveWindow.Zoom = 90

    With xlWB.Sheets(1).Cells
        .Font.Name = "Calibri"
        .EntireColumn.Autofit
    End With

    With xlWB.Sheets(1).range("A1").Entirerow
        .Interior.ColorIndex = 15
        .Font.Bold = True
    End With

'xlApp.Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Set xlApp = Nothing
Set xlWB = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ActiveWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835855.aspx) is a property of the Excel application object.

Your code tries to use it from a worksheet object ...

```vb
xlWB.Sheets(1).ActiveWindow.Zoom = 90
```

When I tested similar code with my own worksheet object, Access threw error #438, *"Object doesn't support this property or method"*.

You should not get that error if you start from your application object variable ...

```vb
xlApp.ActiveWindow.Zoom = 90
```